# HyperGraphQL not returning values when querying my SPARQL endoint

Tags: graphql, log4j, sparql, ontology

I have setup a SPARQL endpoint on my machine using `d2rq` details at http://d2rq.org/getting-started. This is able to expose a standard chinook.db on my `http://localhost:2020/sparql` endpoint. ***I have tested and its returning data.***

I have now created following 2 configuration files as described in the documentation of `HyperGraphQL` as shown below:

**1.chinook.json**

```
{
    "name": "chinook-hgql",
    "schema": "chinook.graphql",
    "server": {
        "port": 8889,
        "graphql": "/graphql",
        "graphiql": "/graphiql"
    },
    "services": [
        {
            "id": "chinook-sparql",
            "type": "SPARQLEndpointService",
            "url": "http://localhost:2020/sparql",
            "graph": "",
            "user": "",
            "password": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

**2.chinook.graphql**

```
type __Context {
    Album: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:2020/ALBUMS")
    label:   _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label")
    comment: _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment")
    albumId: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:2020/vocab/ALBUMS_ALBUMID")
    title: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:2020/vocab/ALBUMS_TITLE")
    artistId: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:2020/vocab/ARTISTS_ARTISTID")
}

type Album @service(id:"chinook-sparql") { 
  albumId: [String] @service(id:"chinook-sparql")
}
```

I am starting the service using the following command:

`java -jar hypergraphql-1.0.3-exe.jar --config /Kiran/Source/HyperGraphQL/chinook/chinook.json`

Now when I open up the http://localhost:8889/graphiql and provide the following query:

```
{
  Album_GET {
    albumId
  }
}
```

the result shows up as:

```
{
  "extensions": {},
  "data": {
    "@context": {
      "_type": "@type",
      "albumId": "http://localhost:2020/vocab/ALBUMS_ALBUMID",
      "_id": "@id",
      "Album_GET": "http://hypergraphql.org/query/Album_GET"
    },
    "Album_GET": []
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

***Can someone tell me why its not returning data***

Also I see there is no logging on the `HyperGraphQL` console to see what its doing or what SPARQL query is being generated because the logging level is set to WARN I Think, as I am new to Java, can someone please tell me how to change the logging level to DEBUG in Log4j. I see it prints this when the service starts:

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.hypergraphql] additivity to [false].
log4j: Level value for org.hypergraphql is  [INFO].
log4j: org.hypergraphql level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [org.hypergraphql].
log4j: Level value for root is  [WARN].
log4j: root level set to WARN
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
```

***Update 1:***
I figured out that the `iri` was missing a part of the namespace in the `Album: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:2020/vocab/ALBUMS")` as a result the query was getting messed-up.

Now the question remains, how can I improve the logging to DEBUG level on log4j so that I can see what is going on inside `HyperGraphQL`